# AspNetCore 2.2 Angular SignalR Negotiate always returns 404 Not found

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

I'm using

AspNetCore2.2 WebAppplication
Angular CLI: 8.3.3
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10

```ts
services.AddSignalR();
app.UseSignalR(config => {
  config.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notify");
});
this.hubConnection.start().then(c => {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

[startup.cs image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myPrf.png)

[startup.cs image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBFIL.png)

Comment: Could be useful if you share with us the http request too.

Comment: And how are you trying to connect to the signalR ? config for ex, 404 is very straight forward, the address its trying to find is not there..

Comment: this.hubConnection.start() makes this request. Did u use Angular and signalR before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your code to see is there any code like below is missing

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/notify")
    .build();

connection.start().catch(err => document.write(err));
```

Update: Change the order of your code like this

```
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
    routes.MapHub<CmsCoreHub>("/cmscore");
});
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Can you add your full startup.cs please. I think the order is matter

Comment: i added images about statup.cs, but i'm not sure so. saved this properly

Comment: @ÖnayYalciner try to change the order like my answer to see if it work

Comment: u r my hero man!! i changed order mvc routing to below and works. (sorry about my English)